# Groupby - Calculate Average of Highest Count Subgroup

Tags: python, group-by

The following data consist of winners of polls within states.

Each row is a different poll (note there are multiple polls within a given state) and contains the winning party and the percentage of the vote they collected:

```
    import pandas as pd

    data = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['Texas','Texas','Texas',\
          'New York','New York',\
          'Pennsylvania','Pennsylvania','Pennsylvania',\
          'Pennsylvania'],
          'Party': ['REP','REP','DEM',\
          'DEM','DEM',\
          'REP','REP','DEM','DEM'],\
          'Percentage of Vote' : [0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.7,\
           .8,.6,\
           .7,.7,.8]})

    data
```

Output:

```
      State        Party Percentage of Vote
    0 Texas        REP   0.7
    1 Texas        REP   0.6
    2 Texas        DEM   0.5
    3 New York     DEM   0.7
    4 New York     DEM   0.8
    5 Pennsylvania REP   0.6
    6 Pennsylvania REP   0.7
    7 Pennsylvania DEM   0.7
    8 Pennsylvania DEM   0.8
```

For each state, I want to calculate and store the average percentage of vote for the party that won the most polls. If two parties won the same amount of polls, I want to keep only the party with the highest average percentage of vote.

Desired output:

```
      State        Party Percentage of Vote
    0 Texas        REP   0.65
    3 New York     DEM   0.75
    7 Pennsylvania DEM   0.75
```

Logic:

REP won more polls than DEM in Texas, so we calculate the average percentage of the vote of both polls REP won and store this number. Notice that the average is calculated as follows: (0.7 + 0.6)/2, with a 2 in the denominator since REP won two polls.

DEM won more polls than REP in New York, so we calculate the average percentage of the vote of both polls DEM won and store this number.

REP and DEM both won two polls in Pennsylvania, but DEM has a higher average percentage of vote (0.75 > 0.65), so we keep DEM and the corresponding average.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work...

First sort by state and party, then get the counts of lines and then the average for each party, the sort descending, remove the non-max values and finally reset index and remove the count column.

```
df =data.groupby(by=['State', 'Party'])\
.agg(count=('Percentage of Vote', 'size'), \
     mean=('Percentage of Vote','mean')).\
sort_values(['count','mean'], ascending=False).\
reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['State']).\
drop('count', axis=1)
df
>> df
          State Party  mean
0      New York   DEM  0.75
1  Pennsylvania   DEM  0.75
3         Texas   REP  0.65
```

Comment: `sort_values(['count', 'mean'])` ?

Comment: Thanks @Deepak, yes corrected it, was trying to do something else, missed undoing it :-)

Comment: Thank you to the two of you!